# New UITableViewCell not calling subview drawRect()

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uiview

I am having this problem for the past two days and I'm trying to get my head around it with no good result.

I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`. Inside the `UITableViewCell` I have a custom `UIView` that I subclassed and drawing it by calling its own `drawRect`.

The drawing for reused cells has no issues and the **cell** is calling its own `drawRect` and the custom subview is calling its own `drawRect` as well.

The problem arises when a new cell is dequeued, the custom subview `drawRect` is not called at all leaving that view empty (non visible)

What I did:

- calling `subview.setNeedsDisplay` has no effect, it's redrawing the reused cells' custom subview but it has no affect on drawing the newer cells' custom subviews.

That's the only thing I thought of and was obvious to try.

Is there a way to force drawing for the subviews for new `UItableViewCell`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` but on the main thread?

Comment: I tried calling that for both: the cell and the subview, it just seems stuck to redrawing the reused cells.

Comment: But I mean in the main thread: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cell setNeedsDisplay]
    });

Comment: Yep, that one. I tried it and it there is no affect on redrawing the subview in the new cell.

Comment: Where would you call it? I am dispaching it at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I am not sure I understood properly, do you want to call cell's or subview's drawRect? If it's the cell it should be fine like that, otherwise, if it's the subview then do the same, but calling the setNeedsDisplay of it: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [cell.yourSubView setNeedsDisplay] });

Comment: Well, I am calling for the subview. However, for the subview, which is the best place to call it?

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath: should be fine, but to make sure what you could do is to call [self setNeedsDisplay] in your subview class, in the method "awakeFromNib", so no need for calling it from the tableView data source

Comment: I tried adding those calls from those locations and they didn't fix it.

Comment: The only thing it comes to my mind is that your subview UI is not linked

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue and force the redrawing of the subview of a custom cell by implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath` regardless of the iOS version (>=7)

Apparently iOS redraw the cell after the height is being calculated.